# How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Is there any possibility to completely disable the new Edge browser?
The old IE could be disabled in Settings → Default Programs, but in Windows 10, the checkbox is missing for Edge.

Is there any way to get rid of Edge, or at least to disable all entry-points?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? Isn't changing default browser enough?

Comment: No, I don't want that any application can open a browser (this happens so often; you press a button and the developer thinks, it would be nice to open a website...^^), but I don't want to surf with this installation. Of course this doesn't help against applications that ship their own WebView, but at least it helps against an accidental opening of a website...
tl;dr
There shouldn't be a browser available on the system so changing the default doesn't work :)

Comment: The final method could be to rename the executable. Should be something like  `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe`

Comment: Could be an idea; but I'm worried that it could break the system (automatic updates e.g.)

Comment: @gronostaj, is not enough, there are features that Windows opens only with Edge, regardless of the default browser, like the pictures search or windows search results

Answer (score 64, accepted):

UPDATE AUGUST 2018: Microsoft keeps changing things a bit, but you can still "Disable" the Edge browser by doing the following:

1. Hold down the Ctrl and Alt keys and tap the delete key, then click on Task Manager.
2. If it says "More details" at the bottom of the Task Manager window, click on it to show more details.
3. Scroll down the list and look for "Microsoft Edge". If you find it in the list, right click on it and select "End task".
4. Now, open File Explorer and find the folder "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" and rename that folder to anything you wish. (I normally just append some text to it like "_remove" so I can easily re-enable Edge in the future if I desire.)

Edge should now be "disabled".

Keep in mind that Microsoft may try to re-enable Edge during a future update...

---

THE ANSWERS BELOW ARE OLDER ANSWERS...

UPDATE: In January 2017 I disabled Edge on a new Windows 10 install by simply renaming the "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" folder. (If you are asked to allow administrator privileges be sure to answer in the affirmative.) Renaming this folder was not possible in the past without following the more detailed steps below. This much simpler approach achieves the exact same results as the more complex instructions below! However, for older installations and/or Windows upgrades the below instructions may still be the only answer.

THE ANSWER BELOW THIS LINE IS THE OLDER ANSWER...

As already stated, the other answers are no longer valid due to changes in Windows 10 -- Microsoft has removed all supported methods for disabling Edge. As of today, this answer still works. Although parts of this answer were given, not all of it was given together in a step by step manner.

- Go to: C:\Windows\SystemApps\
- Open folder Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Right click on MicrosoftEdge file then Properties / Security / Advanced / Click Change (next to owner) and change to your username, then click OK
- Then Click Edit, then add your username and give full permissions
- Rename MicrosoftEdge file to MicrosoftEdge_remove or a name of your choice
- Repeat all above steps for file MicrosoftEdgeCP also
- Done! Edge will not run!

Been running Windows 10 Pro like this on 100+ PCs for several months without issues.

A NOTE REGARDING WINDOWS ANNIVERSARY UPDATE: The Anniversary update appears to undo the above changes and re-enable Edge. In my case I just ran the above steps again, and Edge is once again disabled.

Comment: I was also able to rename Cortana's folder by opening task manager, attempting to rename her SystemApps folder and getting the retry button, switching to task manager and ending Cortana's processes then quickly switching back to the retry renaming dialog and confirmed! Hopefully it stays this way :P

Comment: Yep, after restarting numerous times Cortana is no longer running. I do notice that some updates fail to install and that Action Center bugs me about those, but I'm assuming they're failing because I've disabled Edge/Cortana/removed all the other apps

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Escape opens Task Manager directly, and saves 10 seconds of your life (Instead of using Ctrl + Alt + Delete, then clicking Task Manager"

Comment: This no longer works for me. I just upgraded to 1803. 10-15 minutes after boot, Windows creates an empty "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" folder, which causes the Start Menu to crash when you scroll down to the entry for Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @Michael Your mileage may vary with this solution as it is obviously not supported by Microsoft. I would not be surprised if a Windows Update attempted to reverse this change. However, I still use this method regularly on PCs in the company I work for, including one today (version 1809), and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 v1709. I recently downloaded the EDGE(Chromium) on the PC that already had the EDGEHtml. So, when I installed the new one, I had two EDGE browsers (one HTML, one non HTML). I just disabled the old one using this method and it worked. But the problem is whenever I search for EDGE by going to the search box, the old edge still appears at the top of the result. How do I hide it?

Comment: The edge item wasn't there for me.

Comment: Based on my experience of doing similar things in the past, this might work in the short term but is unlikely to be a long-term fix.  Any Windows update will just "fix" the "problem" you created.

Answer (score 24):

Microsoft Edge is a "trusted" UI App and a core part of the Windows 10 Operating System; it can't be removed by conventional means, just like Internet Explorer could not be removed from previous versions of Windows by conventional means. There are a couple workarounds, however:

You can run PowerShell *as an administrator* and run the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage
```

This will show you a list of all installed Apps and Core features for Windows 10. Scroll down until you find the one with the name **Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge**. Copy (you can use your mouse to highlight the full name and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it) or write down the **PackageFullName**, which will change depending on the build of Windows 10 you are using. For the RTM version released in July, that is:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_20.10240.16384.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe | Remove-AppxPackage
```

or

```
Get-AppxPackage  *edge* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

This should remove the app. Alternatively, you can navigate to the Windows Apps install location:

```
C:\Windows\SystemApps\
```

And right-click the Microsoft Edge folder, `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, and select **Properties**, where you can set the folder and all its contents to **Read-Only** (make sure the checkbox shows a checkmark, not a square). This will prevent Windows from making changes to the folder.

Then, you can open the folder and rename the Microsoft Edge executables (`MicrosoftEdge.exe` and `MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe`) and/or delete them.

Comment: Well, uninstalling from the shell fails (app is core-feature), but deleting and setting Read-Only works (after getting the ownership from TrustedInstaller and so on...^^). Ty 

Comment: Only renaming the folders (Edge and Edge Dev tools) worked for me.  What a pain.

Comment: @ashleedawg I probably need to revisit this answer at some point--Microsoft has made it something of a signature to completely revamp (and revert) everything to do with the OS files/settings (and changes to them) each time they release an update, so parts of this probably no longer apply. I'm sure the PowerShell method will still work, though the package name may have changed since they switched from EdgeHTML to Chromium for rendering Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 10):

Get-AppxPackage *edge* | Remove-AppxPackage no longer works in Windows 10 since RTM.  It throws an error describing that it is part of the operating system and only an administrator can remove it.  But even an administrator can't remove it.  It also mentions turning it off via Optional Features, but it's no longer exposed through Optional Features, nor through PowerShell (Get-WindowsOptionalFeatures).  They really don't want you to disable it.

If you're running Windows 10 Enterprise, you can try using AppLocker to block Edge and set IE as the default.

Answer (score 7):

As has been mentioned, Windows PowerShell is no longer capable of removing Edge.  However, there is a tool that (as of Windows 10 version 1709, build 16299) still can: [wim_tweak](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x_registry_tweak/).  This is a tool that interfaces with the Windows package system and image files.  After downloading the tool, the following script will uninstall Edge:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
echo Uninstalling Microsoft Edge...
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /l
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-Internet-Browser-Package /r
install_wim_tweak.exe /h /o /l
echo Microsoft Edge should be uninstalled. Please reboot Windows 10.
pause
```

You can either download the tool and copy and paste the above commands into a text file and save it as something like UninstallEdge.cmd, or [download the script prepackaged along with wim_tweak](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-edge-browser-in-windows-10/).  In either case, once you have the script and tool in the same folder, you can right-click the script and select "run as administrator".

After running the tool Edge won't be actually removed yet, that occurs on your next Windows restart where the Windows update system kicks in to actually remove Edge.  On your next login it should be gone - properly removed along with entry points.  Caution should be exercised, while this does engage the Windows package system to properly remove it, Edge *is* tightly integrated with Windows and while this personally works well for me, there is no guarantee that this won't break other things in Windows 10.

The same tool is also capable of [removing Cortana](https://superuser.com/questions/977425/uninstall-cortana-windows-10), and listing and removing many other Windows packages.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove Edge so I can see how an application that uses Edge Chromium for embedded web pages reacts when Edge is completely removed.  The following removed Edge entirely from my Windows 10 Pro computer.  I didn't grab the URL, so I can't give credit to the original author.

Run the following from an Elevated CMD window, then restart your computer:

```
cd "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\edge\application\???\installer"
setup.exe -uninstall -system-level -verbose-logging -force-uninstall
```

Replace `???` with the version number of Edge that is installed.

If your OS is 32-bit, also remove  `(x86)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Note!

The solution below is no longer working.
I will leave it as-is, although I consider it obsolete.

I recommend trying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)
instead.

---

*The rest of this post contains my original answer.*

---

I opened PowerShell as an *administrator* and ran:

```
Get-AppxPackage  *edge*
```

This resulted in three hits, for which the `InstallLocation`'s are:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

I opened file explorer and changed the name of those three folders to:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy-BLOCKED
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe-BLOCKED
C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe-BLOCKED
```

It seems to work. I might come back later on to report my experience.

Answer (score 0):

### Note!

The solution below stopped working after
[I made an in-place upgrade of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1750738).
I will leave it as-is, although I consider it obsolete.

I recommend trying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)
instead.

---

*The rest of this post contains my original answer.*

---

> Is there any possibility to completely disable the new Edge browser?

#### Microsoft Chromium – or is it GoogleSoft Edge?

The following method will (almost) completely and permanently
uninstall Microsoft Edge.
<sup>1</sup>

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, copy - paste
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)
`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application`
and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

One of the subdirectories should contain only numbers and dots – the
current version number of Edge.
Double-click it, and then double-click its subdirectory by the name
`Installer`.

[image: Double-click the directory named by the current version number.]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
to *copy* the path to the `Installer` directory.

Open a command prompt as administrator
(<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Type `cd "`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to *paste* the path,
`"` to close the double-quote and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Finally, [paste this command](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10#2-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-2) :
`setup.exe --uninstall --force-uninstall --system-level`
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*That's it!* – No restart is needed. Microsoft Edge will get removed.
(Expect your taskbar to flash momentarily.)

#### References

- [Microsoft Edge official download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge#evergreen)
- [How to remove Microsoft Edge from Windows 10](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10#2-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-2)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Ironically, for this method to work, you must have Edge installed.
So if you somehow already uninstalled it, the very first step is to
[reinstall Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge#evergreen).
Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to prevent the annoying message
[*This app can't open*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03TFm.png) from
occurring every time I wake my laptop from sleep.
For the time being, I'll just have to live with that.
(Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> makes it go away.)

Answer (score -1):

##### Can Microsoft Edge be completely uninstalled in Windows 10?

I've previously posted [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1644027),
and [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1734596).
Each of those solutions worked fine at the time when I posted them
(at least for me).
None of them work after
[I made an in-place upgrade of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1750738).
I'm not the only one to fail uninstalling Edge, as testified by
[this question (solved but not accepted)](https://superuser.com/q/1562783),
[this (accepted but not solved)](https://superuser.com/q/1609171), [this](https://superuser.com/q/1623201),
[this](https://superuser.com/q/1715763), and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1161834).

##### To uninstall or not to uninstall Edge: that is a question …

… but it's *not* the question asked here.
The question asked here is *how* to uninstall or disable Edge.
Yet, these days when [almighty Microsoft tries to convince you that
Edge *cannot* be uninstalled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/why-can-t-i-uninstall-microsoft-edge-ee150b3b-7d7a-9984-6d83-eb36683d526d),
it has become next to [impossible to ask the question *How?* without
getting a bunch of answers back saying *Don't*](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/uninstall-microsoft-edge-windows-11#xenforo-comments-3722636).

If you have locked yourself in by [using Microsoft 365 Apps,
then you should probably *not* uninstall Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/webview2-install).

If you think ['tis nobler in the mind to suffer](https://www.sparknotes.com/shakespeare/hamlet/quotes/page/5/) the pain of
retaining Edge, by all means keep it!

## How to completely uninstall Microsoft Edge

At the time of writing, the latest Microsoft Edge version
is 107.0.1418.35.
Surprisingly, Microsoft Edge shows up in the *Programs and Features*
section of the Control Panel.
Less surprising is that there is no option to uninstall it – if you
click *Change*, the only options are *Repair* or *Cancel*.

#### 1. Shut down Microsoft Edge!

Microsoft Edge is a disobedient software that misbehaves.
Wouldn't you expect it to stop running when you close it?
– It didn't when I closed it.
It seemingly continues to eat CPU, Memory, and Disk indefinitely
after being closed – very similar to how trojan horses and viruses
behave.
And the non-existing option to uninstall it via
*Programs and Features* is combined with [unsolicited startups each
time you wake your computer from sleep](https://superuser.com/q/1224283).
If that doesn't count as crapware, I don't know what does.

To stop it from running, start Windows Task Manager
by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.
Right-click *Microsoft Edge* and click *End task*.
If you also see *Microsoft Edge Update* (`MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe`)
running, or *Microsoft Edge installer*
(`MicrosoftEdge_X64_<version>.exe`),
make sure to end those processes as well.

[image: In Task Manager, Right-click 'Microsoft Edge' > 'End task'.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

#### 2. Remove the software – but keep a backup!

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>,
then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>,
copy-paste `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If Microsoft Edge is installed, you should see at least *three*
subfolders whose names start with `Edge`,
namely `Edge`, `EdgeCore`, `EdgeUpdate` – possibly also
`EdgeWebView`.
I recommend *moving* all these folders to some other place on your
hard drive.
For example, create the folder `C:\programs\MicrosoftEdge`, and
move the four subfolders there.

No restart of Windows is needed. *Microsoft Edge is now uninstalled.*
<sup>1</sup>

###### Optional, but wise

As an extra safety, zip each of the four subfolders, and move the zip
files back to
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft`.
The four zip files is your backup of Microsoft Edge.
<sup>2</sup>

#### 3. Check that Edge is gone

As an extra check, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,
type `appwiz.cpl`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open
*Programs and Features* in the Control Panel.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd>.
*Microsoft Edge* and *Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime* still show up,
but with generic icons.

[image: Microsoft Edge in the Start menu.]

Now right-click *Microsoft Edge* and then *Change*.
Expect to see the message :
*An error occurred while trying to uninstall Microsoft Edge.
It may have already been uninstalled.
Would you like to remove Microsoft Edge from the Programs and Features
list?*

[image: The link in Programs and Features is now broken.]

Click <kbd>No</kbd>.

#### 4. How to remove Microsoft Edge from the Start menu (optional)

That it may still show up in the Start menu isn't a big deal I think.

[image: Microsoft Edge in the Start menu.]

Once you've deleted Edge as described in Section 2,
clicking the Start menu entry will display a *Problem with shortcut*
window.

[image: The link in the Start menu is now broken.]

Clicking <kbd>Yes</kbd> upon the question
*Do you want to delete this shortcut?*
removes the Edge icon from the Start menu, but not the entry.
I don't know if the entry can be removed as well
– and I don't intend to find out.
<sup>4</sup>

#### 5. How to reinstall Microsoft Edge <sup>5</sup>

If you followed my advice to create zip files, unzip them
outside of `C:\Program Files (x86)\`,
and move the four folders back to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft`.

Or go to
[the home page of Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge),
download and install.
<sup>6</sup>
*– I don't recommend it!*

### References

- [How to remove Microsoft Edge | April 2021](https://superuser.com/a/1644027)
- [How to remove Microsoft Edge | July 2022](https://superuser.com/a/1734596)
- [How to perform an in-place upgrade](https://superuser.com/a/1750738)
- [How to disable Microsoft Edge after the June 2020 update](https://superuser.com/q/1562783)
- [Is it possible to uninstall Edge on Windows 10 v20H2?](https://superuser.com/q/1609171)
- [Uninstall Microsoft Edge chromium](https://superuser.com/q/1623201)
- [Can't disable or remove Microsoft Edge?](https://superuser.com/q/1715763)
- [Need to uninstall Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/q/1161834)
- [Microsoft falsely claims that Edge cannot be uninstalled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/why-can-t-i-uninstall-microsoft-edge-ee150b3b-7d7a-9984-6d83-eb36683d526d)
- [Loads of comments saying "Don't uninstall Microsoft Edge"](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/uninstall-microsoft-edge-windows-11#xenforo-comments-3722636)
- [Microsoft Edge WebView2 and Microsoft 365 Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/webview2-install)
- ["To be, or not to be: that is the question"](https://www.sparknotes.com/shakespeare/hamlet/quotes/page/5/)
- [How to stop Microsoft Edge from starting automatically](https://superuser.com/q/1224283)
- [List of *some* web browsers (far from complete)](https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/browsers-list)
- [Some of the most secure web browsers](https://bloggingtips.com/most-secure-browser/)
- [The home page of Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)
- [How to reinstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime](https://superuser.com/q/1751709)

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you don't delete the folder `C:\programs\MicrosoftEdge\Edge`, then
you can still start it :
Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>,
copy-paste `C:\programs\MicrosoftEdge\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`,
and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The major difference is that it now runs on *your* terms, not on
Microsoft's.
And it now behaves more like any other average-Joe chromium browser.

<sup>2</sup>
You may think it would be easier to zip first and *then* move the
folders, but that would yield an *Access is denied* error.
Moving the zip files back isn't necessary, but may make it easier
to remember their location.

<sup>3</sup>
The command `dir *Edge*` doesn't change anything.
It displays what `Edge` subfolders you have.
`/Q` – Quiet mode, doesn't ask before removal with `/S`.
`/S` – Removes the specified directory and all subfolders
and files in it.
In an earlier version of this post, I also instructed to remove
the folders `EdgeWebView` and `EdgeCore` :
`dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\*Edge*`
`Rmdir /Q /S C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView`
`Rmdir /Q /S C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeCore`
`dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\*Edge*`
On second thought, I don't think that is necessary if all you want to
get rid of is Microsoft Edge – *the browser*.

<sup>4</sup>
If you click the entry, you might momentarily be shown
[an empty gray window titled *Microsoft Edge*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBEBj.png).
Nothing else happens.

<sup>5</sup>
Reinstalling Microsoft Edge is not something I would do.
I already have Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Pale Moon.
They are all in [this list of web browsers](https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/browsers-list).
The browser Iridium is included in this
[list of secure browsers](https://bloggingtips.com/most-secure-browser/).
The bottom line is: *there are lots of hazzle-free web browsers*.
Why would I ever want an intrusive browser that Microsoft
desperately tries to force down my throat? – *Without my consent*!
With that said, it's your choice.

<sup>6</sup>
In case you also removed the `EdgeWebView` subfolder, see
[How to reinstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime](https://superuser.com/q/1751709).