# Disable Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows

How do you disable Microsoft Edge in my Packard Bell EasyNote JE69KB?  It is constantly sending pop up videos and games even though it is not my default browser.  I want to disable it if possible.

Comment: "constantly sending pop up videos and games" what type videos or games? Either if they come from Microsoft either caused by a virus I don't think that root cause would be Edge.

Comment: Try this http://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10

Comment: Probably Malware...

Comment: This is 2022, and still no answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)