# Windows 10 remove edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I delete C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe but it remain on the all apps list. It didn't work but I want to remove it too.

Comment: That's a really bad idea.

Comment: All you did was delete the application files, it's been deleted, but you have to remove provision apps specifically, try doing that instead

Comment: You shouldn't. Instead, you are better just to choose another Application to use by default. It is a core component of Windows 10. 

However, if you really want to get rid of it, for a reason I can't understand, look at this SU question.
http://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Answer (score -1):

This has an easy solution.  Unpin Edge from your taskbar and ignore it.  Use another browser like Firefox or Incredimail, or somebody else.  Pin the new browser to your taskbar.  Don't be like me and waste a week trying to find a work-around.