# how do I remove Microsoft Edge from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge, control-panel, components

I know with XP it was possible to remove Internet Explorer as a component, and it looks like Windows 8 made that even easier.  How is IE **removed** from Windows 10 and what are the ramifications?

see also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removal_of_Internet_Explorer

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge

https://askleo.com/how-do-i-reinstall-internet-explorer/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/969358

Comment: "How is IE removed from Windows 10 and what are the ramifications?" -  The exact same way.  Yes;  I issued the downvote.  Your title mentions Microsoft Edge, the body mentions IE11, the question is not clear for that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, fair enough.  I rarely use windows and am not, admittedly, familiar with the distinction between edge and IE.  no prob.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the Windows Apps install location:
C:\Windows\SystemApps\

And right-click the Microsoft Edge folder,

Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe, and select Properties, where you can set 
the folder and all its contents to Read-Only (make sure the checkbox shows a checkmark, not a square). This will prevent Windows from making changes to the folder.

Then, you can open the folder and rename the Microsoft Edge executables (MicrosoftEdge.exeand MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe) and/or delete them. I would rename them.

This is the only way to break/kinda remove edge.