# Need to uninstall Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

BT wants me to uninstall all browsers because of Yahoo hacking issues.  How do I uninstall Microsoft Edge without  problems?  I have Microsoft/Office 2010

Comment: I'd talk to BT again & ask them exactly how they reached that conclusion, & why they thought it might possibly help. *Note for the non-brits* BT is British Telecom, a UK telco & ISP.

Comment: AFAIK, Edge is a component of Windows 10, and is not available for other OS. And, as @Tetsujin suggests, the premise is a *non sequitur*. What does Yahoo and *it's* vulnerabilities have have to do with MS Edge?

Comment: In an enterprise environment, the administrator will make the necessary modifications to your PC. In a private environment, you give them the finger. It’s your PC. // So, unless further justification arrives, I’m VTC this as unclear.

Comment: Uninstalling Edge isn't going to solve your hacking issues you can easily just "reset" Edge which accomplish the samething

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's official answer is that [you cannot uninstall Edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/how-can-i-disable-or-uninstall-windows-edge-from/efef8b42-57b0-44ad-a9d8-831427e8c4b0).  You can, of course, and here's a set of instructions, but it's [hecka complicated and somewhat risky](http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-491534.shtml).  So, I doubt that British Telecom actually intends you to get that far into the guts of Windows 10 just because of something having to do with Yahoo.

P.s.   I wonder if BT actually sent the message.  Sounds like it might be a phishing attempt.

Comment: Sounds like 'clueless phone support done by [mis]reading from a cheat-sheet' to me :/