# Disabled Microsoft Edge using Powershell and now can't get it back -

Tags: microsoft-edge

I removed Microsoft Edge using this tread
[How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10)
and now can't seem to get it back? any hints on how to get it back...can't do it from Powershell in the normal way ..it is not working

Comment: By normal way of reinstalling within Powershell, you mean? `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}` Are you doing this from an elevated PowerShell and what error are you receiving?

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue & I was told the approved method to get it back was to use the Microsoft Store, have you tried that? Depending on how you remove it the package may truly be gone from your hard drive with no retrieval options I believe