# Microsoft 10. Need updated post on how to delete/disable Microsoft edge

Tags: windows

I tried to rename Microsoft Edge folder.  Doesn't work because I am not given the option of becoming administrator.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Answer (score 0):

Related to [How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10), but is more generally asking how to use the Local Administrator account to rename files when there is no prompt to elevate privileges.

**Create a shortcut to run File Explorer as local admin:**

- Navigate to C://Windows and right-click on "explorer.exe"
- Hover-over "Send to" and select "Desktop (create shortcut)"
- Navigate to your desktop, right-click on the shortcut you created
- Select "Properties" and then "Advanced"
- Tick "Run as Administrator"
- Use this shortcut to launch File Explorer as admin and rename