# How to reinstall Microsoft Edge after removing every trace of it in the system?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, microsoft-edge

One day I was angry with Microsoft Edge and I deleted its subfolders under `C:\Windows\SystemApps`, `C:\Windows\WinSxS` and `%AppData%` by using
[FastFind](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/FastFind.shtml)
(which is an application for fast search on Windows).
Therefore, there is no trace of it on my system.
Even PowerShell cannot reinstall it.
(I checked all the methods I could find on Microsoft's website and Windows 10 forums.)

*Can I download and reinstall Edge without resetting Windows?*
Notice that even Windows Update cannot recover it.

**Edit:**
If I transfer the files from another computer, does it work?
Which folders need to be copied?

Comment: "even powershell cannot reinstall it"? Do you mean you used `Get-AppXPackage` to download the Edge package and it failed? Do you have working Internet and a Microsoft account on this system with access to the store? Have you made a new admin account and tried it there? If these things failed, a repair or reinstall from the install media is likely the only the fix.

Comment: I heard from someone that downloading two folders and creating a shortcut will fix the problem but I can't access him.

Comment: Get-AppXPackage doesn't work but if it connects to internet maybe there is a link to download the entire missing folders.

Comment: I'm not certain if you can fix your system as is.  If you want a system without Edge, I think Windows LTSB shipped without it, but it's a hassle to acquire it.  If you want a system with Edge, you probably need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I am also indeed unsure about this but because I did not deleted the registery keys I have hope.

Comment: Maybe trying System File Checker (SFC)

Comment: thanks for your efforts but I need to re-install it for my job

Comment: And I don't think french people know english better than me MR.SIMLEV

Comment: I ask the moderator to delete this question because it is also in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107264/need-help-understanding-error-manifest-is-not-in-the-package-root-while-regist/47926109) unanswered

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us to know what exactly you have deleted.

It's only clear that you have deleted some parts of Windows that should never have
been deleted.

To return your system to a standard running state, I suggest running an in-place upgrade
of Windows, which will keep installed applications, drivers and almost all
Windows settings.

See the article
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Read the article carefully before starting.

Comment: You might not like the answer, but it is the safest solution, since Edge is a very important part of Windows. Destroying is much easier than rebuilding ...

Comment: It is not the answer to this question!

Comment: maybe if anyone explains Get-Appxpackage command I can find any link

Comment: See [How to Reinstall and Re-register Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/28655-reinstall-re-register-microsoft-edge-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: No, I know how to use it but I cannot get what it does

Comment: Where does it connect to download apps?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107264/need-help-understanding-error-manifest-is-not-in-the-package-root-while-regist/47926109)

Comment: A repair would be much better than an upgrade.

Comment: @TylerH: This post is from 5 years ago...

Comment: @harrymc if you think your answer is no longer relevant, then you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

### How to reinstall Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 <sup>1</sup>

> *Can I download and reinstall Edge without resetting Windows?*

– Yes. In one of my current web browsers, I visited
https://microsoft.com/en-us/edge,
which is the home page of Microsoft Edge.

[image: The home page of Microsoft Edge.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

I clicked "DOWNLOAD EDGE", which linked me to :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?form=MA13FJ#evergreen,
where I clicked *Download for Windows 10*.

[image: The download page for Microsoft Edge | Windows 10.]

I chose *English (US)* as my language, and then clicked
*Accept and download*.

[image: License terms for Microsoft Edge.]

I downloaded and double-clicked the file `MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe`.
The downloading and installing that followed, took less than two
minutes.
Microsoft Edge starts automatically.

[image: Microsoft Edge started automatically.]

---

As you can see,
*installing Microsoft Edge is like installing any other web browser.*

> ##### *If I transfer from another computer, which folders need to be copied*?

You'll need to copy all folders under
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\` whose name start with `Edge`.
You should find the following four folders: `Edge`, `EdgeCore`,
`EdgeUpdate` `EdgeWebView`.
It won't matter if the folder `EdgeWebView` is missing, as it should
automatically and silently be created soon after you've started
running Edge on the target machine.
<sup>2</sup>

##### How I removed Microsoft Edge from Windows 10

I removed Microsoft Edge prior to installing it.
I started out by uninstalling according to
[my own instructions on how it can be done](https://superuser.com/a/1750952).
As I want to mimic your situation as much as possible, I opened
the command line as administrator, and went to
`C:\Windows\SystemApps`, `C:\Windows\WinSxS` and `%AppData%`.
In each of those three directories, I ran `dir *edge*`, and then moved
or deleted all subfolders that matched the search.
<sup>3</sup>

### References

- [Edge Chromium versus EdgeHTML / Edge Legacy](https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterprisedesktop/tip/An-introduction-to-Edge-Chromium-vs-Edge)
- [Edge Legacy = EdgeHTML](https://microsoft.fandom.com/wiki/EdgeHTML)
- [The home page of Microsoft Edge](https://microsoft.com/en-us/edge)
- [How to reinstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime](https://superuser.com/a/1751710)
- [How to completely uninstall Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

---

<sup>1</sup>
[When this question was asked in 2018, Windows 10 came with
EdgeHTML](https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterprisedesktop/tip/An-introduction-to-Edge-Chromium-vs-Edge),
which [Microsoft later renamed *Edge Legacy*](https://microsoft.fandom.com/wiki/EdgeHTML).
I don't expect anyone to be interested in Edge Legacy these days, and
I therefore answer how to install the current Edge Chromium only.

<sup>2</sup>
If it doesn't, see
[this rather detailed answer on how to install WebView2](https://superuser.com/a/1751710).

<sup>3</sup>
Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
to open a command prompt as administrator.
Then `cd C:\Windows\SystemApps` and `dir *edge*`.
Do this also for `C:\Windows\WinSxS` and `%AppData%`.
Some of these files and folders are owned by *Trusted Installer*,
which makes it a bit complicated to delete or move them.
But it can be done.
All files and subfolders of those three directories belong to the old
EdgeHTML.
Hence, there is not really any need to remove them.
I wouldn't say I've *removed every trace of Microsoft Edge from my
system*, but I've mimicked what you say you did.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that your question is "How do I install some browser onto my computer, because I deleted my only one".

Using some [PowerShell code from Timothy Warner](https://gist.github.com/timothywarner/5de320a3c648bd9346af8cdbd4db8d14), we can copy paste the command from there directly into PowerShell.

It might take a while, and there's probably a better answer, but if you're in a rush this is a way to fix it.

> ```
> $Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = 'chrome_installer.exe'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe' -OutFile $Path\$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Args '/silent /install' -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item -Path $Path\$Installer
> ```

Comment: OP does say "even PowerShell" cannot fix it, so it might be worth getting info from OP on exactly what PS code they've tried before suggesting a PowerShell solution.