# How to reinstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, microsoft-edge, reinstall

After [I made an in-place upgrade of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1750738),
I decided to remove all subfolders whose name start with `Edge`
from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft`.
<sup>1</sup>
This means I also deleted the `EdgeWebView` directory.

Then I changed my mind and wanted to reinstall the WebView2 Runtime,
so I went to
[the download section of the WebView2 home page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section).
In the leftmost part, I downloaded the *Evergreen Bootstrapper*.

But when I double-clicked it to reinstall WebView2, I got an error
message in my local language.
Translating into English, it says something like :

*The installation failed. Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime has already
been installed on this system.*

---

This question is closely related to
[How to *uninstall* Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://superuser.com/q/1743585)

### References

- [How to perform an in-place upgrade](https://superuser.com/a/1750738)
- [The download section of the WebView2 home page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section)
- [How to uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://superuser.com/q/1743585)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Although there are differences between Windows 10 and Windows 11,
there are also a lot of similarities.
That's why I've chosen to also include the [windows-11](/questions/tagged/windows-11) tag.
Of course, this means that I welcome solutions also for Windows 11 –
even if they haven't been tried for Windows 10 specifically.

Comment: this question was useful, as I made a similar mistake of uninstalling it, then realized my mistake when hyperlinks (including things like mailto links, not just HTTP links) wouldn't open in the corresponding default programs. your question helped me determine which of those downloads I needed to reinstall. Fortunately it looks like the uninstallation was consistent enough that the installer didn't get stuck like it did for you, and links are working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to reinstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `regedit`,
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the registry editor.

Mark and copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`,
press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>,
paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
<sup>1</sup>

Right-click the key `{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`
and choose *Export*.

[image: Export the WebView2 registry key.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

Save the registry file to some place that you'll remember, such as :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView`
<sup>2</sup>

**Now *delete* the key and try running the bootstrap installer again.**
<sup>3</sup>

---

The above solution should work.
But if you still have access to the `EdgeWebView` directory
(in the Recycle Bin),
it might be even easier to restore it into
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft`.
*No other actions should be needed.*

### References

- [WebView2 Evergreen installer no longer adds the registry
  key](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2019)

---

<sup>1</sup>
I found the key at [WebView2 Evergreen installer no longer adds
the registry key](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2019).

<sup>2</sup>
You can name it any way you like, as long as you remember what the
file is about.
I name it :
`HKLM%SOFTWARE%WOW6432Node%Microsoft%EdgeUpdate%Clients%{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}.reg`
which admittedly is very long, but has the advantage of telling
exactly where the key is located in the registry.

<sup>3</sup>
This solution worked fine on Windows 10 version 22H2.
I've not had the opportunity to try it on Windows 11.