# How to disable Microsoft Edge after the June 2020 update

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, microsoft-edge

I had previously disabled Microsoft Edge by changing the name of the executable file,
`C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe`.

Then, the new update of Windows changed this: I tried the same technique, but Edge still works.
I renamed the folder and all Edge executables that I could find.
But I can still launch Edge by typing `edge` into the search bar.

All searches I have done propose the old method.
Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: There are also services (services.msc) dedicated to updating Edge. Their names start with "Microsoft Edge...". Try to set them to "Disabled".

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Answer (score 3):

I renamed the executable file to disable it.  This is a temporary solution that seems to work.  Be sure you have a working alternative browser before you do.

The new location of Microsoft Edge is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`

Rename the file to msedge.ex_
Write down what you did in case you need to undo the changes.

Also, rename the update program at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe`

Rename the file to MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.ex_

You may need to first kill these tasks in task manager before you can rename the files.

You may need to disable Edge after every major Windows update.

Comment: "You may need to disable Edge after every major Windows update." - `Chromium Edge` is not updated through Windows Update.  The author appears to be asking about the current version of Microsoft Edge not Legacy Edge.  *Does your answer apply to the current version of Edge?*

Answer (score 0):

Either I got lucky, or it's not as complicated as people make it out to be. I simply blocked Edge in my firewall settings and now every link opens in Chrome (My default). Worth a shot...