# Uninstall Microsoft Edge Chromium

Tags: windows, uninstall, chromium, microsoft-edge

How can you uninstall Microsoft Edge Chromium on Windows 10?

This will happen, if you ask a good question... look below.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10). This is an automatic generated comment.  I will not respond to any pings directed at me.  Any comments directed at me will be flagged as "it's no longer needed". **Your question really shouldn't link to your own answer**

Comment: A working solution to this question: https://superuser.com/a/1562905

Comment: @ecerer - No; Your edit's from a formatting perspective are worse. Given how one particular user is spamming answers, and links to their answers, I have no patience to edit the question myself. I submitted an answer that included steps to run `setup.exe --uninstall --system-level` when Chromium Edge 77 was launched. I eventually deleted it due to the verified harm it did to my own system stability

Comment: Flag any comment promoting a user's own answer, outside of the automatic comment that is generated for flagging as a duplicate, as a custom flag for a moderator to look into. *I will fix the formatting problems with your question.* I have also protected the question to prevent duplicate answers from being submitted by new users.

Comment: [This answer my question!](https://superuser.com/a/1623202/1269179)

Comment: [A working solution to my question!](https://superuser.com/a/1623202/1269179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PowerShell** (Line by line)

```
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application"
CD *\Installer
.\setup.exe -uninstall -system-level -verbose-logging -force-uninstall
```

**CMD** (Copy all & Paste only once)

```
PowerShell
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application"
CD *\Installer
.\setup.exe -uninstall -system-level -verbose-logging -force-uninstall
```

A scripted way is open!

Comment: Neither of them work on Windows 11 22H2

Comment: @MarcoLackovic - The question is limited to Windows 10.  I would not necessarily expect an answer to also support Windows 11 unless it specifically was mentioned.

Comment: This does not work for me. Nothing happens when I type this command and Edge shortcuts, start menu entry, files and so on are still there. I have `Windows 10 21H2 19044.2251`

Comment: My friend @Henke was happy to say that too, but it still works!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me..... But I haven't restarted the computer, maybe it will work after I restart the computer?

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of Windows 10 (V20H2):

**Internet Explorer** is gone (kept only for compatibility with badly behaved apps)

**Legacy Edge** is gone (replaced by Chromium Edge). I have not seen it in use on any of my Windows 10 V20H2 and beyond computers.

**Chromium Edge** is the only Microsoft browser that Windows 10 has.

It is used in browser based apps Microsoft uses.

So there is no way you can completely uninstall Chromium Edge.

You can only designate a substitute default browser for web work.