# Need to install Edge using admin but have to Uninstall Edge from Windows 11 First

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-edge

I'm running Windows 11 in a Parallels Virtual machine.  One of my vendors has a Rube Goldberg system I must interface.  One of the units requires MSIE emulation but invoking it gives "You must reinstall Microsoft Edge using install as an admin.  Uninstalling Edge is made intentionally impossible by Microsoft.  How do I do it.  I.E. right clicking on Microsoft Edge in the Programs under control panel only allows Repair.  That doesn't help.

Comment: You will have to ask the vendor how they installed Edge as Admin. You cannot uninstall Edge, and I do not think it needs to be installed as Admin. I have not seen that.

Comment: Even if you could reinstall Edge. Reinstalling it as an Administrator wouldn’t do anything. The reason they likely even have that step are for versions of Windows that originally only had IE11.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1623201/uninstall-microsoft-edge-chromium/1752724#1752724) would likely do what you want but it would make it likely impossible to reinstall Edge. So you absolutely shouldn’t use that method

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Edge *cannot* be uninstalled, nor can Internet Explorer *per se* (as opposed an Edge extension that *acts* like IE), run in Windows 10 or 11.

However, you have ways to work around the issue.

- Run an [IE emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)) **inside** MS Edge. You can do this with [Edge Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/).
- Create a [*virtual machine* with an earlier Windows version](https://www.howtogeek.com/102261/how-to-run-internet-explorer-7-8-and-9-at-the-same-time-using-virtual-machines/) that still allows IE to be used. My experience with [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) has been that it is *very* easy to set up, and there are [numerous other good VM's](https://alternativeto.net/software/virtualbox/). Of course, [this would be a VM **inside** the Mac Parallels VM](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2154510-is-it-possible-to-run-a-virtual-machine-inside-a-virtual-machine), but that's what indirection is all about ;-) See also [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine). Just be aware that saving a VM may take 40 GB or more space on the drive, and a VM inside a VM might be  tad slow.