# Can't disable or remove Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, microsoft-edge

I'm following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10) to remove or disable Edge.

I first terminated it in Task Manager. Then, I tried to rename the folders, as suggested, which didn't work:

[image]

I then tried to uninstall it, as suggested, which also didn't work:

[image]

Edge is still opening & operating like normal.

Comment: The **install_wim_tweak.exe** answer to the existing question should still work. Are you looking to disable Edge or uninstall it? What version of Windows 10 are you using exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Edge is built into Windows 10 / 11 and even more so that now deprecated Internet Explorer.

It cannot be Natively removed and you cannot Natively disable the functionality.

Remove any shortcuts to Edge and then set your own Browser (e.g. Chrome) as Default Browser. You can do this and Edge will not be intrusive.  It may come up once in a while.

Go to Settings, Apps, scroll down to Edge and do a Repair. This will fix any issues Edge is having.

There is now not much to choose from between Chromium Chrome and Chromium Edge.

Answer (score -1):

You could use third-party resources that can wipe Edge from your system.
Use an uninstaller like Revo and/or an utility suite like WinUtil.

https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/

https://github.com/ChrisTitusTech/winutil

Trying to force Windows to disable it's own "features" has proven to be counter-intuitive and very difficult, IMO.

Comment: Do not use Revo uninstaller there are so many cases where it caused problems.

Comment: How so? I haven't dealt with any so far.

Comment: Maybe you got lucky but others were not so lucky. Google shows you that there are many people who have had very bad experiences with it.

Comment: Most of the comments about bad experiences with Revo seems very outdated. Of course one should be very careful when using tools that tweak with your OS registries. It would be constructive (at least, since the criticism was so broad) to give some tool that is issue free, since most proprietary system's native tools very rarely helps the user. It is very easy to point out that "some people have problems" with the tool without actually contributing with anything.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.bcuninstaller.com/ for example? I didn't do the downvote btw.

Comment: Pointing out that someone made a bad suggestion is a valuable contribution. Suggesting a better alternative is also a valuable contribution. Bulk Crap Uninstaller is free as in beer *and* speech and opensource.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the suggestion, will try.