# Microsoft Edge Updating even though I disabled the edgeupdate and edgeupdatem services a day ago

Tags: microsoft-edge, automatic-update, software-update, windows-10-v1909, auto-updates

I'm using Windows 10 1909

I woke up to my computer being sluggish so I opened task manager and found out MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe was running and taking lots of CPU, **EVEN THOUGH** I had just disabled `edgeupdate` and `edgeupdatem` yesterday through elevated command prompt. I ended that process, along with another one with a similar name that I forgot, and checked the services tab and it said that`edgeupdate` and `edgeupdatem` were stopped. In hindsight, I should have done checked before I ended the MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe processes but whatever.

Once again I was browsing through my computer with treesize to find out why my C drive keeps filling up, and I discovered my Microsoft programfiles folder was over 400 megabytes more than yesterday.

In the folder, I am presented with four folders.

1. Edge - Inside this folder, the temp folder stands out as being the possible culprit of this space hogging. The temp folder only has one file, the `MSEDGE.7z` file, which is about 400 megabytes.
2. EdgeCore - This folder is about 400 megabytes as well, but inside it are random .dll and .exe files.
3. EdgeUpdate - I'm somewhat sure I deleted the contents of this folder yesterday or the day before, but I can't remember exactly due to my poor memory, but this folder is about 340 megabytes.
4. EdgeWebView - I'm entirely sure I deleted the contents of this folder yesterday or the day before. It filled up again and has about 30 megabytes, about 10 times less than previously.

With this post, I hope to gain suggestions as to which folder I should clear the contents of, should it be of no necessity to keep, as well as finding out how to stop Microsoft Edge from updating completely, ie. stopping my Microsoft programfiles folder from filling up for no reason. My best bet is probably the `MSEDGE.7z` file but I know almost nothing about it. It could be my edge browsing history for all I know, and googling it yields no clear answer as to what this file is.

Comment: Your Windows is very far out of date.  On up to date Windows 11 and Windows 10, Edge works fine and does not overuse CPU. Do you have too many tabs open at one time? That might be an issue.

Comment: If I remember correctly Edge also has planned tasks for updating. Not sure what you are trying to achieve to use an outdated Windows and you are also trying to keep your browser in an outdated version. May be if you would explain why there may be easier (and more secure) ways to achieve what you want/need.

Comment: I rarely ever use edge at all. Chrome is my main browser. I want to keep Edge as is, I don't want it to update at all. The main thing I'm trying to solve with this post is which folder is harmless to clear in my Microsoft programfiles folder.

Comment: @Anon753123 I wrote up something similar that might be worth looking at for Chrome here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update/57824611#57824611, but if there is a will, there is a way. Sometimes you have to brute force things to ensure compliance with an unorthodox approach. In any event, I ditched that whole thing and started allowing it to auto update. In the name of web browsing security and also to ensure it works with all websites without screaming about security issues, etc. in that configuration environment.

Comment: I suspect there are Edge equivalents to that basically which would just be a trivial matter to figure out. If you're technical, that might be a starting point for you at least; otherwise, someone may be able to fish you something for the day here. Edge is Chromium based like Chrome and has GPO, reg values, scheduled tasks, etc.

Comment: Have you looked into using the group policy to prevent Edge from being updated?  All it requires is installing the Administrative Templates for Edge and enabling the group policy.  I know there is one because Chrome and Firefox both have one.

Comment: *I want to keep Edge as is, I don't want it to update at all.*
I think [my solution](https://superuser.com/a/1750952) comes pretty close to what you want to achieve. By moving the four Edge folders outside of `C:\Program Files (x86)\`,
MS Edge behaves more like an ordinary chromium browser.
As long as you don't start MS Edge, I'm pretty sure it won't update either.