# How to uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2

Tags: windows, windows-11, uninstall, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to uninstall the Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime?

The Control Panel (*Programs and Features*) gives the option to
"Change" but not to uninstall WebView2.
The reason I want to remove it is that I am in the process of
debloating Windows 11, and I am curious as to how to remove it,
because Windows doesn't give that option.

Here is what I have achieved:

[image]

but after updating Windows today, I noticed that Webview2 started
to open tons of widgets, increasing the number of processes.

Comment: It is internal Windows runtime for handling of all HTML-like content in your computer and normally you can't remove it. As long as you're not making debloated version for some special purpose - you shouldn't ever remove it.

Comment: Are you looking to uninstall Microsoft Edge or Webview2, one is a browser, the other is part of the .NET Framework that is built into Windows 11

Comment: Yeah; On Windows 11 it’s still built-in if you don’t use any native applications that use it it’s left unused.

Comment: Keep in mind that other applications you may install later on this machine could also depend on Webview2.  Removing it from your system would be problematic.  IHMO, it's not bloat.

Comment: You might benefit from using a third-party debloating tool that describes the items -- see https://github.com/n1snt/Windows-Decrapifier, for example. Also look at https://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/ for Windows **10** services that can be disabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to completely uninstall Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)

Comment: Related : https://superuser.com/questions/1784952/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-edge-webview2-packaged-installation-via-cli

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to uninstall microsoft edge webview2 by following the instructions found on windowsreport website:

https://windowsreport.com/microsoft-edge-webview2-runtime/

1. Click on the magnifying glass icon and type cmd inside the search bar.
2. Right-click on the top result to open the Command Prompt app.
3. Select Run as Administrator.
4. Next, navigate to the path where it is installed by typing the command below and pressing Enter:
   `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer`
5. Next, type or paste the following command to silent uninstall it and press Enter:
   `.\setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall`

Comment: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer\"`

Comment: See here for uninstalling the `offline/manual` installation method --> https://superuser.com/a/1785622/465645

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thanks. One change in my windows 11, the path was C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\120.0.2210.91\Installer