# How to uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2 - Packaged Installation - Via CLI

Tags: windows, uninstall, microsoft-edge

I have a severe hate for `Microsoft Edge WebView2`. No other program has forced installation like this.

Occasionally, I install it manually via a downloaded package.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

All the links online talk about uninstalling via the following, but I noticed it only works when Microsoft installs it without my consent.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer\"

setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall
```

When I install via the Packaged version, I have to uninstall via "Remove Apps/Programs" under settings UI.

**How can I uninstall via CLI?**

Note: This is similar to [How to uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://superuser.com/questions/1743585/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-edge-webview2) but I'm specifically talking about the version installed offline and uninstalling via CLI.

Update:

`MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX64.exe /silent /uninstall`

Has Error:
[image]

Further Update:

- This issue is compounded by the fact that when I install offline, MS will still update/install via `setup.exe` found in the normal `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer\"` location. If the installation is upgraded, I think I need to use the `setup.exe`.

I'm basically looking for a script that will do both, try and look/use `setup.exe` and look for `offline` installer. Ironically, it seems that the `setup.exe` is deleted after I uninstall.

I need to be able to basically install and uninstall at will because I'm getting CORs issues and different results based on install status. The trouble is I can't control installation/updates.

Comment: Try that ( from "Downloads" folder ): MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX64.exe /silent /uninstall

Comment: Does flyby downvoter care to explain what needs more explanation?

Comment: Not me man. What other way is there to install, aside the exe file? You can probably run Powershell command to install it from the store, if it exists there. Edit: Oh I see you've added a comment. Do you mean it was resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing manually, it installs to `%LocalAppData%`.

I had to also remove the `--system-level` flag. Note: If I didn't remove this flag, I got no error, but it also didn't work.

Here is my batch script as it stands:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls

::MS Persistent Installation
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer\"
setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall

::Manual/Offline Insallation ::NOTE: No "--system-level"
cd "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\Installer"
setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --verbose-logging --force-uninstall

pause
```