# Can't uninstall Edge Webview2 Runtime - Uninstall Button Greyed Out

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have a severe hate for `Edge webview2 runtime`.

I have spent countless hours figure out how to uninstall it.

Today, I noticed my uninstall script (that I run multiple times a day..) doesn't work any more.

The "uninstall" button is also greyed out.

Any ideas?

Here is how I'd usually uninstall via CLI:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\116.0.1938.69\Installer"
setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall
```

And here it is in the Uninstall Apps UI:

[image]

**Any ideas how I force this to uninstall?**

Comment: Current version of Edge isn’t 116.0.1938.69 try a while card after the first 1. As recently as August 22nd the potential duplicate was confirmed to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://superuser.com/questions/1743585/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-edge-webview2)

Comment: @Ramhound You will see I am the one who commented on that answer w/ the wildcard comment...

Comment: I rarely look at commnets to answers since they rarely have anything useful in them.  Anything of important should be in a question body or answer body.

Comment: @Ramhound I completely disagree I tend to find relevant information all the time in comments... but thanks for ur efforts regardless

Comment: It’s rare but those helpful answers should be edits to contributions instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this has to do with Microsoft, I'm guessing something changed internally by IT at company to block the "Uninstall" button. I was able to go home and uninstall the same revision, although I am running a different version of Windows at home.

I basically figured out if I "bork" the directory then it doesn't work, which is fine for my use case/same as uninstalling.

Here is my scripted version of what I did:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\1*\"
del /s /q "*" 2>nul
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this script may not work anymore. We might have circumvented guards against uninstalling Edge/WebView2 Runtime in the past, but this has been hardened recently. It is applied to both Windows 10 and Windows 11 (mostly because they are pre-installed with WebView2 Runtime).

Anyway, this is not recommended as WebView2 is a required component and if removed, product functionality in some apps like Outlook will be affected.

**Relevant articles**

Windows 10:
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2022/12/14/delivering-microsoft-edge-webview2-runtime-to-managed-windows-10-devices/

Windows 11:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#the-evergreen-runtime-distribution-mode

Microsoft Edge WebView2 and Microsoft 365 Apps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/webview2-install

Comment: Unfortunately, your computer is not a great source... I found I was able to uninstall it on a different computer. Those articles are old and just about Webview, no details on uninstall