# How to stop Microsoft Edge from updating in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, updates, microsoft-edge, windows-services, auto-updates

About a month or two ago, I was using TreeSize to check the contents of my C: drive since it was filling up even though I wasn't downloading it. I discovered that in ProgramFiles, Microsoft's Edge Folders were the culprit behind the storage usage. I found a supposed 'solution' on superuser, which warranted me to disable the EdgeUpdate service, and months later, today, I was checking my computer again with TreeSize, and I found out that the contents of the Edge folders were updated a few days ago, and EdgeWebView, which I'm pretty sure I deleted after disabling the EdgeUpdate service thinking it'll never come back again, reappeared, with hundreds of megabytes worth of contents. I'm using a mid-end laptop, so I only have one C: Drive and the files I have inside it are important, so even a few dozen megabytes are salvageable.

TL;DR: I don't even use Microsoft Edge at all, but I still want to keep it on my computer if Chrome goes awry, but I want to keep it a certain version. Windows apparently updates Edge behind my back every once and a while, and I don't want that happening since it takes up space and also slows down my computer without my knowledge. So, I want to disable Edge updates once and for all.

Comment: I assume you have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/1734596#1734596) duplicate?

Comment: The top answer in the post you linked is the one I read and referenced in this post. The specific answer you linked talks about removing Microsoft Edge which is what I explicitly said I didn't want to do in my post.

Comment: It appears the only way to prevent Microsoft Edge from updating and preventing updates from installing is through a group policy, but unless your Windows instance is connected to an Active Directory domain, it cannot be used. I presume the command you used to uninstall EdgeWebView, was the following command: `setup.exe --uninstall --msedgewebview --system-level --verbose-logging --force-uninstall`? You don't actually indicate, which answer you followed, so forgive my ignorance of my previous comment.

Comment: Why does my Windows instance need to be connected to an Active Directory domain? What does that have to do with me trying to disable Edge from updating? One solution I thought of, was just blocking whatever domains causing my things to automatically update, with my Firewall (my newest post you just edited a few minutes ago). That way, the service(s) will think I am offline.

Comment: "Why does my Windows instance need to be connected to an Active Directory domain?" - Because the policy that allows you to configure Edge NOT to install updates only applies to Windows instances connected to an Active Directory domain. Hence the reason my comment indicates, if your instance is NOT connected to an Active Directory domain, the policy that allows you to prevent Microsoft Edge from updating cannot be used. I might add that Chrome has a similar service, which will restart itself when disabled. **Keep in mind domains change constantly.**